# How can I perform database migration using Entity Framework 4.2?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, migration

I'm just starting to dive into ASP.net MVC3. I come from a Django background. One of the things I love about Django, is the add-on called "South". It lets me modify my Models in code, and then I run a command, it figures out what has changed, and it updates the database accordingly.

If I add, remove, or rename a field with the "code-first" approach in EF4, what happens? Does it just add or remove the field, and that's it? What if I want to do something like add a new field, and then perhaps run a Linq-to-SQL query to populate the new field, and *then* remove the old field? *And* I want a record of this so that when I go to deploy the change on my production server, it will run those 3 commands in sequence.

Is there something like that? Or how do people tackle situations like this? (It is pretty common...)

---

**Edit:** Found some links.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76082/is-entity-framework-code-first-a-bit-meaningless-useless-in-production-and-what
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx
- [Using EF4 Code First: How can I change the Model without losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5870037/65387)
- [Deploying database changes with EF 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5861991/65387)
- https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-with-magic-walkthrough-automatic-migrations.aspx (Woo!)

Comment: MVC is only about presentation, not about persistence. You might want to change the title to ask about Entity Framework.

Comment: @driis: Ah...yeah. Lots of new things here. Everything's de-bundled... MVC3, Razor, EF... a lot to learn :D

Comment: Nothing has changed between EF 4.1 and EF 4.2 regarding the migration problem. All the old questions and answers are still valid.

Comment: @Slauma: So...there's no good solution? We're hooped? Update the code carefully, and run your migrations manually?

Comment: That's what I do currently. There is something in progress: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx But it's an Alpha version and will likely still take some time before it is finished.

Comment: There's a bunch of attempts at Migrations for .NET and EF ([Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) and a few more), but nothing has really captured any mindshare. There's a bunch of SQL-based solutions, too - [RoundhousE is one](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/) I've looked at. Microsoft has [Code First Migrations in Alpha 3 stage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx) but it's not ready yet

Comment: @Slauma: Woo! That's good news. I think I have quite a ways to go before I'm ready to take this project out of dev anyway :)

Comment: You may want to check [EntityFramework.SchemaCompare](http://github.com/kriasoft/data) migrations strategy for EF Code-First (it's currently in development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an excellent tutorial from Microsoft MVP David Hayden:
http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-and-entity-framework-database-migrations

Not sure about 4.2 - but I installed the latest EF (4.3.1) and it worked like a charm.

Pretty impressive - and I'm a Rails guy :P

Comment: Nice! This was the one thing keeping me back from moving to MVC. Databases change, there's no way around it. You need a way to deal with it!

Answer (score 2):

What happens depends on your initialisations, i'll discuss the "standards" using the dot net ways.

Take a quick-deep dive into:

[Database Initialization Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715123%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) 
 - Look at the top, here the "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" is used, so it will always drop the Database and recreate it (you have other possabilities). - It says how EF should react on database changes.

Here are the possible [Database Initializations](http://sankarsan.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/dbinit.png)

If you want Migrations, there are 2 ways:
- [Magic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-with-magic-walkthrough-automatic-migrations.aspx)
- [No-Magic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx)

What you should know, is that Migrations is actually 1 week old (EF 4.2), it has been implemented in EF 4.1, though not with full support (Different DB, ...), but it's improving.

It depends on how much time you have, but i'm waiting to implement 4.2 and EF Migrations, i'll implement it in a "test-project" on the end of the week, see if everything goes well and respond to the Ado.Net Team Blog (see links on Magic - No-Magic). Although i don't think there will be any problems.

Best of luck on your choice :)

Comment: Migrations is in Alpha 3. I wouldn't call that 1 week old; it's still in the womb. Nevertheless, I'll try it out too when I get to that bridge :) Thanks.