# Update database schema without dropping data?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I started using EF using database first and generating my diagram from the database.

Now I have switched and made many changes to my diagram and would like to update my database schema without data loss. However, generating database from the diagram seems to drop all the tables and recreate them.

I have found 'data migrations' for code first. Is there anything similar for model first, or any way I can maintain the data?

I am using VS 2012 with EF5

Comment: Deploy to a test database, then do a difference between the test database and production using a tool of your choice that produces difference scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861991/deploying-database-changes-with-ef-4-1

Comment: Except "generate database from model" turns all your nice DefiningQueries (views) into tables and trashes the edmx file in the process.

Comment: In that case I use schema compare functionality of Visual Studio. It works quite well. Renamed columns are problem, but apart of that it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to search into SO site,

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87/

> After installation, when you choose "Generate Database from Model..."
>   it'll popup a new wizard and you can choose "Generate Migration T-SQL"

Another way is to use custom t4 to generate DbMigrationsConfiguration and DbContext from your model and you don't need to run Enable-Migration at all. Simply run Add-Migration and Update-Database in the Package Manager Console

http://blog.amusedia.com/2012/08/entity-framework-migration-with-model.html

Comment: I did search SO, but as I listed in my question I am using VS2012 and EF5, neither of which is supported by that tool, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem, t4 templates are the best way

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate how I would use T4 templates to accomplish this..?